# What's the shortest way to add a constant value to all the elements of an int[]? How about matrix addition?

Tags: java, arrays

I've got an array of int's. I need to add 1 to each of its elements. What's the shortest, most general way to add a given constant to each element, that is, without explicit loops? I've looked online and keep getting pages about adding an element *onto* an array (i.e., concatenation).

Isn't there something more elegant than looping through each element and adding the constant? Is there some sort of standard library method?

For that matter, how would one add two arrays together (i.e., matrix addition) without an explicit loop?

Comment: There's nothing built-in to the Java language.  You may find a library that handles array operations such as this but under the covers it will use iteration.  There may also be libraries that use JNI to invoke vector operations using hardware instructions or the GPU to parallelize the code.

Comment: What do you meant by the shortest ? the code you write ? or the speed ? how large is your array can be ? why a loop is not allowed ?

Comment: @RangiLin, 1. Obviously shortest would refer to the code he writes. "Short" and "long" is not how speed is measured. 2. The array length should be immaterial. 3. It's not a question of being allowed. He is looking for a terse and more elegant way to write the same thing.

Comment: @RangiLin, I meant short, just as **missingfaktor** says, but fast would also be of interest. Perhaps I'm just spoiled by past use of IDL, but it seems to me that there has to be some terse way to work with vectors--one that wouldn't require dragging in a whole new library for (what should be) a basic operation, or writing all kinds of mini-methods to handle common matrix/vector operations.

Comment: Trust me, @JohnK, you have not yet even scratched the disappointment surface with the Java Collections Framework API.  You might check out Guava (which has a `Lists.transform` that manages to combine both my and @missingfaktor's answers in a general way).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can write the two cases above with [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/).

---

**1. Adding 1 to each element:**

It's a functional programming library, and so it does not provide mutating operations. But you can easily add them yourself.

```
public static <A> void transform(Array<A> xs, F<A, A> f) {
  for(int i = 0; i < xs.length(); i++) {
    xs.set(i, f.f(xs.get(i)));
  }
}
```

**Use:**

```
transform(yourArray, Integers.add.f(1));
```

---

**2. Adding two matrices:**

Let `xss` and `yss` be two matrices, both of types `Array<Array<Integer>>`. Then you can add them with:

```
 xss.zip(yss).map(new F<P2<Array<Integer>, Array<Integer>>, Array<Integer>>() {
   public Array<Integer> f(P2<Array<Integer>, Array<Integer>> p) {
     Array<Integer> xs = p._1(); 
     Array<Integer> ys = p._2();
     return xs.zip(ys).map(new F<P2<Integer, Integer>, Integer>() {
       public Integer f(P2<Integer, Integer> q) {
         return q._1() + q._2();
       }
     });  
   }
 });
```

---

This may feel more verbose than necessary, and that is because Java does not support lambda expressions yet. In the meantime, [IDEs can help](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/03/closure-folding-in-intellij-idea-9-maia/) make such techniques more approachable.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it's cool to learn about Functional Java. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnK, do you know about Scala? It's a functional language that runs on JVM, and is fully interoperable with Java libraries. In it, your two examples would be written as: `xs.transform(1 +)` and `(xss, yss).zipped.map { case (xs, ys) => (xs, ys).zipped.map(_ + _) }` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If an unmodifiable result is ok, and you're not stuck to using arrays, you could use a cute trick to delay the addition until the last possible moment.  But as soon as you need to visit the whole result array, any performance benefit is lost and the code ends up being more complicated than necessary.

```
public class OffsetArrayList extends AbstractList< Integer > {
    private final List< Integer > liUnderlying;
    private final int iOffset;
    public OffsetArrayList( int iOffset, liUnderlying ) {
        this.iOffset = iOffset;
        this.liUnderlying = liUnderlying;
    }
    @Override
    public Integer get( int iIndex ) {
        return liUnderlying.get( iIndex ) + iOffset;
    }
    @Override
    public Integer set( int iIndex, Integer iNewValue ) {
        return liUnderlying.set( iIndex, iNewValue - iOffset ) + iOffset;
    }
    // etc.
}

// create new array
int[] aiInput = new int[] { 23, 98, -45 };
// two object allocations, but no new array created and no additions performed
OffsetArrayList alPlusOne = new OffsetArrayList( 1, Arrays.asList( aiInput ) );
// one addition performed; constant time
assert( alPlusOne.get( 0 ) == 24 );

// benefit murky, as we are adding to the same element repeatedly
for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
    assert( alPlusOne.get( 2 ) == -44 );

// benefit lost, input destroyed
int[] aiOutput = alPlusOne.toArray( aiInput );
```